# php page to redirect to another

Tags: php, redirect

I have a php page which should be included in otherpage but no directly. Lets assume it as 1.php and the other page as 2.php

**1.php**

```
<?php
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/1.php"){
       header("Location:2.php");
   }
   else
   {
       //some code here
   }
?>
```

**2.php**

```
<?php
   include("1.php");
?>
```

this worked well on `localhost/1.php` and have been redirected to `localhost/2.php`
but this had made a problem with `localhost/1.php?somegetmethod=data` I found that anyone can access this page by typing `?something=something` at the end of 1.php url. How to change the code which can redirect all url which starts with localhost/1.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check if a substring is at a given position like this

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/1.php") === 0) {
```

this checks if the `REQUEST_URI` starts with `/1.php` (= is at position 0)

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/1.php")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: surely and have got the result

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains URI of requeted page, in yoour case it's `1.php?somegetmethod=data`.

Change code like:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/1.php") === 0){
    header("Location:2.php");
}else{
    //some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you often see, for instance in MediaWiki, WordPress and many other such applications, is this:

1.php

```
if ( !defined( 'YOURAPPCONSTANT' ) ) {
  // You could choose to redirect here, but an exit would make just as much  
  // sense. Someone has deliberately chosen an incorrect url.
  echo "Cannot directly call this file.";
  exit( 1 );
}
```

2.php

```
define('YOURAPPCONSTANT', 'It is defined');
include('1.php');
```

That way, 2.php is the entry of your application, regardless of the url used to reach it. I think this is a much safer and more flexible way, and it is used so often for a reason.